# How to write a function-defining function which stores the function arguments in a stack?

Tags: programming, evaluation, assignment, error-tracking

I have a function-defining function

```
SetAttributes[DefFn, HoldAll];

DefFn[f_[args___], body_] :=
 f[args] := body;
```

I am trying to modify this function to record the function name and the values of its arguments on a stack for error-reporting purposes.  I have a function `WithStackFrame` which adds this information to a list, and I am inserting a call to this function into each definition:

```
DefFn[f_[args___], body_] :=
 f[args] := WithStackFrame[f,body];
```

This allows me to give a stack backtrace when reporting errors.  This works.  The problem comes when I try to store also the values of the function arguments.  A naive

```
DefFn[f_[args___], body_] :=
 f[args] := WithStackFrame[{f,{args}},body];
```

does not work because `args` is actually the sequence of patterns.  The closest I have got is

```
DefFn[f_[args___], body_] :=
 Module[{argValueExprs,x},
    argValueExprs = {args} /. x_Pattern :> x[[1]];
    f[args] := WithStackFrame[{f,argValueExprs},body]];
```

For the purpose of testing, you can use

```
WithStackFrame[sf_, expr_] := Print[sf];
```

However, running this gives

```
DefFn[f[x_], x^2];

f[3]  
(*
{f,{x}}
*)
```

when I really want `{f,{3}}`.  For some reason, the `x` is not being evaluated in a scope in which the function arguments are visible.

Comment: You might want to add a note that `WithStackFrame` needs attribute `HoldAll` for the test case to work as stated.

Comment: @Albert I'd say, `HoldFirst` rather than `HoldAll`, to allow the body to evaluate.

Comment: @Leonid: actually now that I think about it even `HoldFirst` seems not really necessary, it was my mistake (I had a definition for `x` hanging around) that caused it was needed in the first place. Once the function does what it is supposed, the actual arguments will be used so the hold attribute should usually not be necessary at all, so it might be best to ignore my comment...

Comment: @Albert Yes, but the arguments passed to the first argument of `WithStackFrame`, may be expressions which may evaluate (the function being executed may be `HoldAll` itself), so in that case `HoldFirst` for `WithStackFrame` would prevent that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could name the patterns

```
DefFn[f_[args___], body_] := 
  f[s : PatternSequence[args]] := WithStackFrame[{f, {s}}, body];
```

Comment: This is pretty cool. I use this myself often, but for this question, this did not cross my mind - too bad. Big +1.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin thanks. In an unrelated matter, I just found some behaviour that I found interesting and commented in the main chat but they had their minds somewhere else. I now discovered it's based on the Update[] issue but I would like to know what you think, if it would be useful, if you have a minute :)

Comment: I like that for it's simplicity

Comment: @Rojo You are a dangerous person :). You may find my answer in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/84839750cff64e58) relevant to your suggestion - I used there the one-step evaluation method similarly to your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @LeonidShifrin... For the link and comment, not so much for the dangerous... A little limitation of using DownValues however is that they don't work well with Flat (which can't get any more complex). An advantage is that it isn't based on a bug, hehe

Comment: @LeonidShifrin by the way, a couple of days ago I made a function that wraps definitions of Downvalues and such (in symbols already defined), to make those new definitions be "on top" in the downvalues list and not the default bottom. You know of any good way to do this other than prepending the downvalues by hand like I did? It seems like a common need

Comment: @Rojo Been there, done that :) To my knowledge, you have to use `Prepend`, `RotateRight`, `RotateLeft` or the like. Sometimes this by otself is not enough, since they are reordered back. I use the trick of adding a symbol like `f[x_]/;(tag;True):=r.h.s.`, so that the ordering engine can no longer find the relative generality. This is also handly because it is easy to remove those definitions, testing for the presence of the `tag` symbol in `DownValues`. You can localize `tag` with `Module`, if you want.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin good tips

Comment: This would basically solve my problem, and was posted before Mr. Wizard's solution, but his is a bit cleaner so I'm actually using that.  Anyway, thanks for all the help! StackExchange is amazing!

Comment: @IanHinder In that case, you should accept my answer.  I realize this is to my own advantage in this case, but [I also advocate selecting the *best* answer when it is not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124610/multiple-background-subregions-in-mathematica-grid#comment-7106505), and other major contributors have agreed with me.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, your answer basically rewrites my idea... Ok, in a cleaner and possibly less buggy way, and adds a suggestion of "rewriting the problem", changing "what he really wants" in a, I also agree, more natural way. Aren't the praises and the +1 of the accepted answerer enough satisfaction? Hehe ;)

Comment: Rojo, I argue that my first method is in fact a separate idea that gets around the problem in a different way.  If on the other hand Ian is using the `Unevaluated` method then I suggest deleting it from my answer and appending it to yours.

Comment: BTW, I voted for yours, too.

Comment: Oh no! I caused a ruckus! I didn't use the Unevaluated, as I used the more natural f[args] as an argument to the (held) WithStackFrame.  I would say the original question was "how do I store the arguments in a stack", and the split into f and args was just my example of something I had tried and which had not worked.  Mr Wizard's answer is the simplest and cleanest, which is why I use it, but I do feel it is almost a derivation of Rojo's.  Anyway, I will go with the community consensus, if you can point me to it in the meta site?

Comment: @IanHinder haha, I don't think we care that much, and I agree with what's been said

Answer (score 5):

You need a parser for the argument patterns. I wrote a simplistic one for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255999/hold-any-argument/7256401#7256401). I will reproduce it here to keep things self-contained:

```
splitHeldSequence[Hold[seq___], f_: Hold] := List @@ Map[f, Hold[seq]];

getFunArguments[Verbatim[HoldPattern][Verbatim[Condition][f_[args___], test_]]] := 
     getFunArguments[HoldPattern[f[args]]];

getFunArguments[Verbatim[HoldPattern][f_[args___]]] := 
     FunArguments[FName[f], FArgs @@ splitHeldSequence[Hold[args]]];

(*This is a simplistic "parser".It may miss some less trivial cases*)

getArgumentNames[args__FArgs] := 
   args //. {
     Verbatim[Pattern][tag_, ___] :> tag, 
     Verbatim[Condition][z_, _] :> z, 
     Verbatim[PatternTest][z_, _] :> z
   };
```

With this, your code might be:

```
ClearAll[DefFn];
SetAttributes[DefFn, HoldAll];
DefFn[f_[args___], body_] :=
  With[{funargs = getFunArguments[HoldPattern[f[args]]]},
     With[{fargs = Join @@ getArgumentNames[funargs[[2]]]},
        SetDelayed @@ Hold[f[args], WithStackFrame[{f, fargs}, body]]]];
```

Using it:

```
DefFn[f[x_], x^2];

?f
Global`f
f[x_]:=WithStackFrame[{f,Hold[x]},x^2]
```

and thus:

```
f[3]

(*
 ==> {f,Hold[3]}
*)
```

**EDIT**

Here is a somewhat more general and more robust argument parser:

```
ClearAll[parse];
SetAttributes[parse, HoldAll];
parse[(Condition | PatternTest | Optional)[arg_, _]] := parse[arg];
parse[(HoldPattern | Optional)[arg_]] := parse[arg];
parse[Verbatim[Pattern][sym_, _]] := Hold[sym];
parse[Verbatim[Repeated][p_, ___]] := parse[p];
parse[(Blank | BlankSequence | BlankNullSequence)[___]] := Hold["NotAPatternVar"];
parse[(Longest | Shortest)[arg_, ___]] := parse[arg];
parse[Verbatim[PatternSequence][args___]] := parse[args];
parse[a_ /; AtomQ[Unevaluated[a]]] := Hold["NotAPatternVar"];
parse[args___] := Join @@ Map[parse, Unevaluated /@ Unevaluated[{args}]];
parse[f_[args___]] := {Hold[f], parse[args]};
```

With its help, the function would be written as:

```
ClearAll[DefFn];
SetAttributes[DefFn, HoldAll];
DefFn[f_[args___], body_] :=
  With[{fargs = parse[f[args]]},
     SetDelayed @@ Hold[f[args], WithStackFrame[fargs, body]]];
```

Some examples to try:

```
ClearAll[f, ff];
DefFn[f[x_], x^2];
DefFn[
  ff[x_,PatternSequence[Shortest[y__], p__] /; {Length[{p}] < Length[{y}]},z_, (q_) ..] /; 
         x < z, 
  {x, y, p, z, q}]
```

Note that the trick `SetDelayed@@Hold[lhs,rhs]` is needed to fool the variable renaming mechanism of enclosing `With`. This is explained in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6236458/plot-using-with-versus-plot-using-block-mathematica/6236808#6236808).

Comment: Faster and more elaborate than mine -- of course :-)

Comment: @Albert You should remove this "of course" - I was faster by pure luck, and your solution is simpler.

Comment: You should also include `Optional` in your parser as it wraps `Pattern` like `PatternTest` does, e.g. `FullForm[HoldPattern[a_:0]]` returns `HoldPattern[Optional[Pattern[a, Blank[]],0]`.

Comment: @Leonid: I just deleted mine, since it just is a simpler version of yours. You might want to add an explanation that `SetDelayed@@Hold[...]` is just a trick to avoid the localization of `SetDelayed` that was the root of the problem that Ian has seen.

Comment: @rcollyer Yes, you are right. Actually, the parser itself is not written well, because it should be true recursive decsent, while I took a short-cut and substituted it with repeated rule application through `ReplaceRepeated`. I will take some time and rewrite it, then update the answer - and incorporate your suggestion as well.

Comment: @Albert Ok, will add that. I will actually also rewrite the parser, and then update everything.

Comment: @rcollyer I added another implementation for the argument parser, which I like better. Probably not complete either, though.

Answer (score 4):

I would do this:

```
DefFn[f_[args___], body_] := 
  lhs : f[args] := WithStackFrame[lhs, body];
```

Then make `WithStackFrame` `HoldFirst` and do de-structuring there.  For example:

```
SetAttributes[WithStackFrame, HoldFirst]

WithStackFrame[f_[args___], expr_] := Print[{f, {args}}];
```

If for some reason this were unacceptable I would do:

```
DefFn[f_[args___], body_] := 
  lhs : f[args] := WithStackFrame[{f, List @@ Unevaluated[lhs]}, body];
```