# How to REALLY Hold arguments and capture FullForm?

Tags: evaluation, meta-programming

I'm trying to write an expression deconstructor or `FullForm`-capturer; might even call it a parser, maybe, but that might be too glorious a word.

I got some great ideas from ["Head and everything but..."](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2449/head-and-everything-except-head), but have plunged headlong back into the fog of my own limited understanding again, which got even foggier when I tried to understand ["...function arguments on a stack..."](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/how-to-write-a-function-defining-function-which-stores-the-function-arguments-in). I'd be most grateful for ideas, advice, and more clarity.

Consider this example: `a + b + c`.  We know its `FullForm` is `Plus[a, b, c]`, and I can "capture" that `FullForm` in a `List` with something like

```
Cases[{a + b + c}, head_[args___] -> {head, args}]
```

which produces

```
{{Plus, a, b, c}}
```

Now I go get myself all drunk on recursion and think I can write

```
SetAttributes[capture, HoldAllComplete];
capture[expr_?AtomQ] := {Head@expr, expr};
capture[head_[args___]] := {head, capture /@ {args}};
```

so that something like `capture[a + b + c]` gives me fantastic detail

```
{Plus, {{Symbol, a}, {Symbol, b}, {Symbol, c}}}
```

or, in stunningly beautiful `TraditionalForm`

$\left\{\text{Plus},\left(
 \begin{array}{cc}
 \text{Symbol} & a \\
 \text{Symbol} & b \\
 \text{Symbol} & c \\
\end{array}
\right)\right\}$

All is well till I try

```
capture[1 + 2 + 3] ~~> {Integer, 6}
```

OH NO, it's not Holding inside!  What I want, of course, is

$\left\{\text{Plus},\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 \text{Integer} & 1 \\
 \text{Integer} & 2 \\
 \text{Integer} & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)\right\}$

My problem is revealed by `traceView2`, which I got from ["... clearest way to represent ..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5459735/the-clearest-way-to-represent-mathematicas-evaluation-sequence)

[image: Trace of offending call]

We see that `1 + 2 + 3` arrives held to `AtomQ`, as expected, but greedy old evaluator grabs it right there and smooshes it into 6. Everywhere else in the trace, the same thing happens.  I don't know an easy way to stop the evaluator inside my `capture` faction.

It has occurred to me to copy and adapt the code of `traceView2` to my application, since it exploits `Trace` to get ahead of the evaluator, and I will proceed that way unless I receive a cool answer here.  In my dreams I imagine something like

```
SetAttributes[capture, DudeReallyHoldAllCompleteEverywhere];
```

or

```
SetAttributes[capture, HoldAllComplete, Levels -> Infinity];
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, that's my made-up meta-notation for "produces".  It's not part of Mathematica, it's my secret abbreviation for my descriptions of Mathematica.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, what you have here is some classic example of what is called "Evaluation leaks". So, first, the corrected code:

```
ClearAll[capture]
SetAttributes[capture, HoldAllComplete];
capture[expr_ /; AtomQ[Unevaluated[expr]]] := 
    {Head[Unevaluated[expr]], expr};
capture[head_[args___]] := {head, capture /@ Unevaluated[{args}]};
```

Now, you can inspect it and compare to your version, to see that you had three such "leaks": in the pattern-testing `AtomQ` (which does not hold its arguments), in the r.h.s. `Head[expr]`, since `Head` also does not hold them, and, perhaps most importantly, in `capture/@{args}`, since `Map` does not hold its arguments either.

So, evaluation leaks are cases when some code which wasn't supposed to evaluate, actually does. Some most frequent situations which lead to evaluation leaks are either when the code is being passed to / anylized by a function which does not hold it properly, or when some parts of held code are extracted during destructuring (e.g. by `Cases`), not being wrapped in a holding wrapper head.

The standard thing to do to prevent the evaluation *once* is to wrap your code in `Unevaluated`, which I did above. To prevent evaluation in a  persistent manner, we usually wrap an expression in `Hold`, `HoldComplete`, or perhaps some custom holding wrappers with `Hold`-attributes, but in such cases you have to take care to strip the holding wrapper when no longer needed.

Some more involved examples of parse-like functions which avoid evaluation leaks can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867757/has-anyone-written-any-function-to-automatically-build-a-dependency-graph-of-an/8869545#8869545) (function `depends`) and also [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/how-to-write-a-function-defining-function-which-stores-the-function-arguments-in/2209#2209) (function `parse`). The problem of evaluation leaks is a very frequent one once you start working with pieces of unevaluated code, which is particularly common when writing parser-like functions, macros, and other metaprogramming-related functions. You can look at some references in my recent answer on [metaprogramming](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2335/metaprogramming-in-mathematica/2352#2352), for some more links to code where prevention of evaluation leaks was essential.

Comment: Some slight confusion -- I notice you did NOT write `capture[head_[args___]] := {Unevaluated[head], ...`.  Indeed, I checked it out with `f[x_]:=3;capture[f[42]g[a]]` and I get `{Times, {{f,{Integer,42}},{g,{Symbol,a}}}` implying that, in the R.H.S. of `capture[head_[args___]] := {head, ...`, `head` is NOT evaluated. Why not? Doesn't `List` not Hold its arguments?  I'm slightly confused. (I think an extra `Unevaluated` wrapper would be harmless documentation, wouldn't it?)

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Well, `head` surely *is* evaluated, so, had you assigned say `f=1`, and you would have that evaluated. It is just that in these cases, head was a symbol not having a value, so it evaluated to itself. I left `head` to evaluate since I thought you wanted it that way. In fact, to cover also composite heads, the proper way would be this: `capture[head_[args___]] := {capture[head], capture /@ Unevaluated[{args}]}`. I am off to bed now, but feel free to edit my post and replace `capture` with this code, if you feel this better addresses your goals. Thanks for the accept b.t.w.

Comment: very nice!  you are really helping to clear my fog!

Comment: @Reb.Cabin Glad I could help. I love this type of questions :)

Comment: My example was a stupid mistake; I should have tried `f[42][a]` and I would have seen `3[a]`, proving that the Head of `f[42][a]` is `f[42]`, that is, that function-ness is greedy leftward; the head includes everything except the last bracketed arguments list.

Comment: another question -- in the first rule for `capture`, with condition `AtomQ`, if `Unevaluated[expr]` is an Atom (passes `AtomQ`), then isn't it always the case that `Unevaluated[expr] === expr`, and therefore that `{Head[Unevaluated[expr]], expr} === {Head[expr], expr}`.

Comment: @Reb.Cabin An atom may be a symbol holding a value, in which case `Unevaluated[expr]` is not the same as `expr`. The question is then, what behavior *you* want. Perhaps, `{Head[Unevaluated[expr]], expr}` may be more confusing in this case, but `{Head[expr], expr}` may also be confusing. Try experimenting to see what I mean. Sorry, I am really not here already :)

Answer (score 4):

A very useful idiom for avoiding evaluation leaks is:

```
foo= Function[{expr, pattn, levels},  
  Extract[Unevaluated[expr], Position[Unevaluated[expr], pattn, levels], HoldComplete], {HoldAllComplete}]
```

This function `foo` finds parts of `expr` at specified `levels` that match `pattn` and most important it wraps them in `HoldComplete` before they get a chance to evaluate.  Example usage:

```
foo[2*12/(Sqrt[6+3]+1), _Plus, {1,-1}]
```

> `{HoldComplete[Sqrt[6+3]+1], HoldComplete[6+3]}`

EDIT
An earlier version didn't work because I didn't have the first argument of Position wrapped in Unevaluated. That is fixed above and I had a chance to verify that it works.