# Function that counts the number of arguments of other functions

Tags: function-construction

I have a newbie question: is it possible to write a function that counts the arguments (total and optionals) of a given function? Possibly it should be able to work with built-in and custom functions as well.

For example, if I define

```
f1[x_Integer] := x + 1;
f2[x_Integer, y_Integer: 1] := x + y;
g[x_Real, y_] := x - y;
```

I would like to have

```
countArgs[f1]
{1,0}
countArgs[f2]
{2,1}
countArgs[g]
{2,0}
```

and also, for example,

```
countArgs[Sin]
{1,0}
```

thank you.

@celtschk

Well, I didn't even know the use of UpValues, but basically what I am asking is the number of inputs the function needs, I don't care what the function does with those inputs. In your examples I would say

- {Infinity,0} for foo? It's more a question than an answer, sorry, but I had not thought aboute these unusual cases.
- this is nasty, I didn't think of a case like that either, I would say {3,{2}}, the {2} meaning exactly 2, to avoid bar[1,2], which is not legal.
- {2,0} but just because you wrote f[g,g], so it's practically a guess, I don't know what are UpValues and if they go against the spirit of my question by messing with the function. I hope I was clear.
- the last one I would say {3,0} as they were flattened.

Thank you, I start seeing that my question is not so obvious because there are too many complicated definitions for functions to take into account.

For now I understood that is possible with built-in functions with

```
SyntaxInformation[f]
```

(thank you Heike) but that mybe is a little too much asking for a general custom function.

Comment: For built in functions you can use `SyntaxInformation`. For example `SyntaxInformation[Mod]` returns `{"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _, _.}}` indicating 3 arguments of which the last one is optional.

Comment: What should it return for `foo[x__Integer] := {x}`? And what for `bar[x_] := 1; bar[x_, y_, z_] := 2`? Should it also consider `UpValues` like `f[g,g] ^= 0`? And would `a[x_, {y_, z_}] := x+y/z` count as taking two or three arguments?

Comment: This becomes challenging, output for the following cases ? `f[x_]:=1,f[x_,y_]:=1,f[x_,OptionsPattern[]]`

Comment: Then there are things like `p[n_][x_] := (* stuff *)`...

Comment: @imnage_doctor
In order I would say:
- {1,0}
- {2,0}
- {1+n,n} assuming that OptionsPattern takes up to n optional values

Comment: @Jane T. for `foo[x__Integer] := {x}` `x` is a `BlankSequence` and thus can be any number of arguments. Then `{1,0}` would not necessary be correct...

Comment: @J.M What is the difference between f[x_,y_] and f[x_][y_] ? Is f[x] alone defined in the latter case? If not, I would say {2,0}, otherwise {2,1}.

Comment: @freedieknets thanks, I didn't see the double downscore, in that case i'd say {Infinity,0}, but I think it's pushing the question too far...

Comment: "Is f[x] alone defined in the latter case" - well, it allows you to do things like `f[x] /@ {a, b, c, ...}`

Comment: @JaneT. If all three definitions for `f` coexist perhaps the output might be a list: `{{1,0,False},{2,0,False},{1,0,True}}` where `{_,_,_}->{required,optional,options}`

Comment: @image_doctor yes, very clever indeed. But i don't know how to work that out either with all the extreme examples posted.

Comment: @J.M. in that case y in f[x_][y_] is sort of optional... but it's getting too confusing for me, too many special cases I didn't think about.

Comment: @JaneT. Just wait a few minutes and mma.se will work its magic.

Comment: What about this pattern, `f[a:x_ + y_:4]`, what should your function return, then?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is my attempt. The function below will work on functions with default args and options, as well as those having multiple definitions. I made the following assumptions:

- Only `DownValues` - based definitions are considered
- Default arguments, if present, are always to the right of mandatory arguments.
- Options, if present, are always to the right of all other arguments, and are declared either by `OptionsPattern[]` or `opts:OptionsPattern[]` pattern.

Here is the code:

```
ClearAll[countArgs];
SetAttributes[countArgs, {HoldAll, Listable}];
countArgs[f_Symbol] := 
   With[{dv = DownValues[f]}, countArgs[dv]];

countArgs[Verbatim[HoldPattern][HoldPattern[f_Symbol[args___]]] :> _] :=
  countArgs[f[args]];

countArgs[
   f_[Except[_Optional | _OptionsPattern | 
         Verbatim[Pattern][_, _OptionsPattern]], rest___]] :=
  {1, 0, 0} + countArgs[f[rest]];

countArgs[ f_[o__Optional, rest___]] := 
  {0, Length[HoldComplete[o]], 0} +  countArgs[f[rest]];

countArgs[f_[_OptionsPattern | Verbatim[Pattern][_, _OptionsPattern]]] := 
  {0, 0, 1};

countArgs[f_[]] := {0, 0, 0};
```

This function represents a mini-parser for the function's declarations. It returns a list of 3-element sublists, of the length equal to a number of `DownValues`. In each sublist, the first number is a number of normal arguments, the second one is a number of default arguments, and the last one (which can only be `0` or `1`), tells us whether or not there are options declared.

Some examples:

```
ClearAll[f1, f2, f3, f4, g]
f1[x_Integer] := x + 1;
f2[x_Integer, y_Integer: 1] := x + y;
f3[x_, y_, z_: 1, q_: 2, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := x + y + z + q;
f4[x_, y_: 1] := x + y;
f4[x_, y_, z_] := x + y + z;
g[x_Real, y_] := x - y;
```

Now applying our function:

```
countArgs /@ {f1, f2, f3, f4, g}
```

> ```
> {{{1, 0, 0}}, {{1, 1, 0}}, {{2, 2, 1}}, {{1, 1, 0}, {3, 0, 0}},{{2, 0, 0}}}
> ```

Comment: Impressive! Thank you Leonid. Can I accept more than 1 answer? Yours truly deserves it. (PS. you typed two f4).

Comment: @Jane T. You can only accept one answer, and generally it is a good idea to wait a little bit before accepting any, so that people are motivated to write alternative answers. You can also unaccept an already accepted answer and accept another one if you like it better (please not that this is just generaly FYI, not an advice for this particular case). As for `f4`, this is intentional. In case you did not know, Mathematica functions can have more than one definition at the same time, and the one to be used is the one whose pattern will first match.

Comment: @Leonid Shifrin Excellent :) Perhaps the 3rd element of the result might reflect `Length@Options@f` ?

Comment: @image_doctor Thanks :). " Perhaps the 3rd element of the result might reflect `Length@Options@f`" - I don't think this is really necessary, but it could be a possibility (although `Options` might not be defined at the time when definitions are considered, although this is admittedly a rather contrived situation).

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Perhaps counting options should be an option to `countArgs` ;)  I think `Options` returns an empty list if the options for `f` aren't defined. Which I guess could be interpreted as logically correct from one viewpoint.

Comment: @image_doctor Well, perhaps :).

Comment: @JaneT. Please feel free to unaccept my answer, I won't be offended :-)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Your code is very sophisticated, thank you.

Comment: @JaneT. Thanks for the accept. You may be also inetrested in somewhat similar discussions [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/how-to-write-a-function-defining-function-which-stores-the-function-arguments-in/) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/automatically-generating-a-dependency-graph-of-an-arbitrary-mathematica-function/4345#4345), where, at least in my answers, somewhat similar parsers were constructed.

Comment: @SimonWoods You are very kind. I did it.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I'll check the links, thank you.

Comment: Leonid, I hate to burst your bubble, but what about `f[a : {{_, _} ..} : {{1, 2}}] := {a}` or `g[a : x_ + y_: 4] := {a, x, y}`? I get `{{{0, 1, 0}}, {{1, 0, 0}}}` from mapping over them.

Comment: @rcollyer I think this is the correct behavior. Your `f` has a single optional arguments `a`, thus I get `{{0,1,0}}` for it. Your `g` has a *single non-optional* argument `Plus[x_,y_:4]`, which, while having an optional part, is, as a whole, non-optional, so I get `{{1,0,0}}`. You probably meant `g1[a:(x_+y_):4]:={a,x,y}`, in which case, I get `{{0,1,0}}`, since the argument is now indeed optional.

Comment: I thought I had you. You're right. I missed the fact that the `4` was attached to the `y`, and not the whole sum.

Comment: @rcollyer Not so easy :). But I don't pretend to have captured all cases, I am sure it is not too difficult to construct cases where my current implementation will fail. It is however easily extensible.

Comment: But, that doesn't mean we won't stop trying. :) (Of course, the more we try, the harder it gets to succeed as you get better.) I just remember how difficult it was to get something like this to work consistently when trying to determine variable names, so you're right, there is likely flaws.

Comment: @rcollyer I certainly got a lot better during my time on SO and then here, particularly in this sort of parsing stuff. But, as you said, writing a complete parser is no easy task, since you have to account for all details, and special cases.

Answer (score 9):

This only works for simple cases such as those in the question:

```
countArgs[f_]:=Module[{countarg},
countarg[x___,y___Optional]:=Length/@{{x},{y}};
(DownValues[f]/.f->countarg)[[All,1,1]]]
```

E.g.

```
f1[x_]:=x+1;
f2[x_,y_:1]:=x+y;
g[x_,y_]:=x-y;
g[x_]:=x+1;

countArgs@f1
Out[6]= {{1,0}}

countArgs@f2
Out[7]= {{1,1}}

countArgs@g
Out[8]= {{2,0},{1,0}}
```

The example for g shows how it produces a list of answers for functions with more than one definition.

Comment: Thank you Simon, works perfectly. As others has showed, a general answer is asking too much.

Comment: I am new to stackexchange, so I was eager to vote for an answer as a sign of my appreciation, I was not aware it was a better custom to wait (as Leonid explained). Your answer is very good even if I have to choose Leonid.

Comment: @JaneT. Voting for many answers is fine, but you can only "accept" (click the "tick") for one answer. If several people give good answers, it is definitely fine to vote for them all (click the uparrow above the number at the top left of each answer), and "accept" the one that is most useful for *you*. And a belated welcome to Mathematica.StackExchange!!

Answer (score 6):

This is not intended as an answer, or not at the moment. I just thought it was worth mentioning a built-in that is documented but not in the Doc Center

> ArgumentCountQ[head, len, min, max] tests whether the number len of
> arguments of a function head is between min and max.
>
> ArgumentCountQ[head,len,{Subscript[m, 1],Subscript[m,
> 2],...,Subscript[m, i]}] tests whether the number len of arguments of
> a function head is one of the Subscript[m, i].

**EDIT**

Ok, this is totally useless to the question, but for now I'm leaving this since people seem to like to learn new functions.

This is the predicate that normally issues the famous message *xxx called with 2 arguments; X arguments are expected.*.
It receives the head, the number of arguments input into the expression, and the number of expected arguments, either as a range or as a list of possible numbers.
If the number of arguments is right, it returns `True`. If it's not, it returns `False` and issues a message.
Furthermore, there's the function `` System`FEDump`NonOptionArgCount `` possibly useful for argument counting. A sample of use could be

```
f2[i___, OptionsPattern[]] := {i} /; 
  ArgumentCountQ[f, System`FEDump`NonOptionArgCount[{i}], {2}]
```

A perhaps less simple but more common use case could be

```
f[i_, j_, OptionsPattern[]] := i + j
f[i___] := (ArgumentCountQ[f, 
   System`FEDump`NonOptionArgCount[{i}], {2}]; Null /; False)
```

The first definition is your usual function definition.
The second one catches all, and in all cases runs the first argument of the `CompoundExpression`: `` ArgumentCountQ[f, System`FEDump`NonOptionArgCount[{i}], {2}] ``.
This gives `True` if the number of arguments passed, not counting the options, is exactly 2, but we don't care about that. We only care about the message it issues when it's not. After that, the definition is not applied since there's a hard-coded condition set to `False`, so it returns unevaluated.

Comment: Can you give an example of that in use?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, check the edit

Comment: Thanks.  I'm torn about voting; on the one hand I think it's cool you're digging this up, on the other I don't think it answers the question, as you said.  I think I have to go with the latter, but consider yourself +1 on *real* reputation. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, it's ok, this one was for solidarity, I wasn't expecting votes. I'm writing an answer to the return's second argument question and I expect upvotes there ;)

Comment: which question is that?

Comment: [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6815/109)

Comment: I forgot to come back to that one.  I'll look for your answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, there it is

Comment: +1. it's a very "professional looking" option for a custom function.

Comment: The first argument of `ArgumentCountQ` can be anything?

Comment: You will like ``Developer`CheckArgumentCount`` than ``System`FEDump`NonOptionArgCount``