# Examine function parameters programmatically

Tags: expression-manipulation, meta-programming

I write a lot of scripts in Mathematica and I'd like to eliminate the boilerplate that parses command-line arguments and assigns them to variables of the correct type before doing the real work. I was thinking of accomplishing the following way.

1. Find a function called `main`.
2. Look at the list of its parameters `[a_Integer, b_Real, c_String]`.
3. Attempt to convert the elements of $ScriptCommandLine into those parameters.
4. Call main with those parameters.

This way, each script can simply contain a function main that will be called with the appropriate parameters from a bootstrap script.

I'm trying to figure out how to accomplish #2. I've been trying to use `Definition`, but I can't figure out how to parse the output. Is there a better way?

Comment: How do you plan to handle functions with multiple or complex patterns?  E.g. `f[x_,y_]:=x+y; f[x_]:=x;` or `g[x_,a_:1]:= a x` or `h[n_?OddQ]:=n+1; h[n_?EvenQ]:=n`?  It might be better and clearer to just specify the type list separately from a function definition.

Comment: I wanted to take care of the simple case for now.

Comment: You may find [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7040/function-that-counts-the-number-of-arguments-of-other-functions/7044#7044) and [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/how-to-write-a-function-defining-function-which-stores-the-function-arguments-in/2209#2209) answers useful (the latter only the last part), in both I construct various argument parsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found one way to do this. If `f` is the function you're interested in, the following will give you a list of lists of argument types, so long as the definitions are of the form `f[firstParam_Integer, secondParam_Real, ...]`.

`Cases[DownValues[f], RuleDelayed[func_, _] :> Level[func, {4}]]`