# Is function polymorphism possible in Mathematica

Tags: function-construction

Is there a way to have polymorphic function definitions in Mathematica?  I looked around online and didn't anything discussing it.

Comment: possible with type checking `len[x_?StringQ] := StringLength@x;
len[x_?ListQ] := Length@x;
len["greeks"]
len[{10, 20, 30}]`

Comment: I have discussed some forms of polymorphism [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/33919/81). Also related: [How to create strong types?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4636/how-to-create-strong-types).