# Applying rules to rewrite expressions that contain patterns

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement, hold, rule

I'm trying to write a rule that can rewrite a pattern that exists in another expression. For some reason, this is proving to be more challenging than I expected ... most likely because I'm not totally understanding how Mathematica implements its pattern matching mechanism.

Here's my simple test case:

```
foo = Foo[a: {A,B,C}, b: {a,b,c}]    (* FullForm yields: Foo[Pattern[a,A],Pattern[b,B]] *)
```

I want to rewrite the portion `b : {a,b,c}`  with some other expression, like `Reverse[<b>]` which should yield: `b : {c,b,a}`.

Here's what I've tried to far (none of which works):

```
foo /. (b:X_) -> Reverse[X]                 (* #1 produces Foo[b: {a,b,c}, a: {A,B,C}] *)

foo /. Hold[(b : B_)] -> Reverse[B]         (* #2 no effect *)

foo /. HoldForm[(b : B_)] -> Reverse[B]     (* #3 no effect *)

foo /. HoldPattern[(b : B_)] -> Reverse[B]  (* #4 same as case #1 *)

foo /. (b : B_List) -> Reverse[B]           (* #5 reverses both a:{} and b:{} *)
```

Comment: You may also be interested in expression parsers. Two examples which come to mind are [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2206/how-to-write-a-function-defining-function-which-stores-the-function-arguments-in/2209#2209) and [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4343/automatically-generating-a-dependency-graph-of-an-arbitrary-mathematica-function/4345#4345) (function `depends`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foo /. HoldPattern[Pattern][Verbatim[b], x_] :> Pattern[b, Reverse@x]

(* Foo[a : {A, B, C}, b : {c, b, a}] *)
```

See

[Pattern matching a pattern with patterns](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17892/pattern-matching-a-pattern-with-patterns/17895#17895)

[How to match a pattern with a pattern?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2778/how-to-match-a-pattern-with-a-pattern)

for some in-depth discussions on similar constructs.