# Map patterns to values

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, hold

Suppose I have a list of named patterns:

```
listofPatterns = {a_Integer, b_Real, c_?StringQ}
```

I would like to have a mapping from a pattern to a certain value like:

```
foo[HoldPattern[a_Integer]] = 1;

foo[HoldPattern[b_Real]] = 1.5;

foo[HoldPattern[c_?StringQ]] = "foo";
```

In order to apply that on my list

```
foo /@ listofPatterns
```

And I expect to have `{1, 1.5, "foo"}` as a result. What is the best way to achieve that?

Thank you, Davit

Comment: Can you give a specific example? This is my input, this is my desired output. I do not understand what it means to *apply a pattern* to a list.

Comment: Sure, This is my input  `foo /@ listofPatterns` and this what I except `{1, 1.5, "foo"}` the question is to define foo correctly.

Comment: Related, possible duplicates: [(2778)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2778/121), [(17892)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17892/121), [(43923)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43923/121)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you need a pattern to match what is normally used *as a pattern*, you should use [`Verbatim`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Verbatim.html):

```
foo[Verbatim[Pattern][_, Verbatim[Blank[Integer]]]] := 1

foo[Verbatim[Pattern][_, Verbatim[Blank[Real]]]] := 1.5

foo[Verbatim[PatternTest][_, StringQ]] := "foo"

foo /@ {a_Integer, b_Real, c_?StringQ}
(* {1, 1.5, "foo"} *)
```

When writing patterns like this, it's helpful to look at the full form of the patterns you want to match:

```
Column[FullForm /@ {a_Integer, b_Real, c_?StringQ}]
(* 
Pattern[a,Blank[Integer]]
Pattern[b,Blank[Real]]
PatternTest[Pattern[c,Blank[]],StringQ] 
*)
```