# Extract what symbol is set by SetDelayed, Set, TagSet, UpSet, SetAttributes, etc

Tags: syntax, code-review

One of the recent features of the [Mathematica Plugin for IntelliJ IDEA](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24556/187) ([www.mathematicaplugin.halirutan.de](http://www.mathematicaplugin.halirutan.de/)) is a *Structure View* which let's you see information about several definitions that are done in a source file. It currently looks like the left side of the image below:

[image]

To provide such a feature, I need to extract which symbol is set when the user uses things like

- `lhs = rhs` or `lhs := rhs`
- `s /: patt = rhs` or `s /: patt := rhs`
- `lhs ^= rhs` or `lhs ^:= rhs`
- `Options[sym] = rhs`, `Attributes[sym] = rhs`, `SyntaxInformation[sym] = lhs`, `Format[sym] ] = rhs`, `N[sym] = rhs`, `Default[sym] = rhs`
- `sym::tag = rhs`

Since in IDEA I cannot evaluate code like one can in *Mathematica*, I have to extract all those information from inspecting the abstract syntax tree (`TreeForm` in Mathematica). For this, I have a so-called *visitor* which walks through the tree and collects information. One can easily write such a visitor (or expression parser) in *Mathematica* itself. I have written a very basic version of such a visitor, which takes a expression like `f[x_]:=x^2` and extracts the symbols which is set and the type of the assignment. Partly, I have simply copied code from [Leonids answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2209/187). Before giving the code here are my

**Questions:** Can the visitor below be improved? Are there missing cases, things I haven't thought of, things that don't work correctly? Especially `UpSet` is interesting because there, more than one symbol can be set at the same time.

---

Here is a very basic visitor which uses simple pattern matching to check the structure of an expression:

```
ClearAll[visit];
SetAttributes[visit, {HoldAllComplete}];
visit[s_Symbol] := MakeBoxes[s];
visit[(h : (SetDelayed | Set))[lhs_, _]] := {MakeBoxes[h], visit[lhs]};
visit[(h : (TagSetDelayed | TagSet))[a_, _, _]] := {MakeBoxes[h], visit[a]};
visit[(h : (UpSetDelayed | UpSet))[_[args__], _]] := {MakeBoxes[h], visit[args]};
visit[HoldPattern[Options[sym_] = _]] := {MakeBoxes[Options], visit[sym]};
visit[HoldPattern[Attributes[sym_] = _]] := {MakeBoxes[Attributes], visit[sym]};
visit[HoldPattern[SetAttributes[sym_, _]]] := {MakeBoxes[Attributes], visit[sym]};
visit[HoldPattern[SyntaxInformation[sym_] = _]] := {MakeBoxes[SyntaxInformation], visit[sym]};
visit[HoldPattern[Default[sym_] = _]] := {MakeBoxes[DefaultValues], visit[sym]};
visit[HoldPattern[MessageName[sym_, tag_] = _]] := {MakeBoxes[Messages], visit[sym], MakeBoxes[tag]};
visit[Verbatim[Format][sym_] := _] := {MakeBoxes[FormatValues], visit[sym]};
visit[HoldPattern[(Set | SetDelayed)[N[sym_], _]]] := {MakeBoxes[NValues], visit[sym]};

visit[(Condition | PatternTest | Optional)[arg_, _]] := visit[arg];
visit[(HoldPattern | Optional)[arg_]] := $Failed;
visit[Verbatim[Pattern][sym_, _]] := $Failed
visit[Verbatim[Repeated][p_, ___]] := $Failed;
visit[(Blank | BlankSequence | BlankNullSequence)[___]] := $Failed;
visit[(Longest | Shortest)[arg_, ___]] := $Failed;
visit[Verbatim[PatternSequence][args___]] := $Failed;
visit[a_ /; AtomQ[Unevaluated[a]]] := $Failed;
visit[args___] := List @@ Map[visit, Hold[args]];
visit[f_[args___]] := visit[f];

SetAttributes[StructureView, {HoldAll}];
StructureView[sets_Hold] := Column[List @@ Map[visit, sets]]
```

And here are some positive test-cases that work

```
StructureView[Hold[
  f[x_] := x^2,
  SetAttributes[sym, {HoldAll}],
  Options[Plot] = {PlotRange -> Automatic},
  square /: area[square] = a^2,
  area[rectangle] ^= a*b,
  int /: rand[int] = Random[Integer],
  h /: f[h[x_]] = x^2,
  SyntaxInformation[
    f] = {"ArgumentsPattern" -> {_, _, OptionsPattern[]}},
  N[f[x_]] := Sum[x^-i/i^2, {i, 20}],
  f::usage = "f[x] gives (x - 1)(x + 1)",
  area[square1, square2] ^= s^2,
  Format[bin[x_, y_]] := MatrixForm[{{x}, {y}}]]]
```

And here are some test-cases that (correctly) fail because they are semantically not valid

```
StructureView[Hold[
  h_ /: f[h[x_]] = x^2,
  f_[x] := x^2,
  f_[x_] := x^2,
  "f"[x_] := x
  ]]
```

#### Final notes

- I haven't included vector-set like `{a,b}={1,2}` and the special notation `a[[1]]=4` on purpose.
- I someone doesn't want to post a complete answer, but wants to discuss something, then ping me in the [plugin chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8636/intellijidea-plugin-for-mathematica)

Comment: Humm, there's the manual way of defining `XValues[sym]={lalalla}` for all `DownValues`, `OwnValues` etc.

Comment: Also you could `DeleteDuplicates` on `List @@ Map[visit, Hold[args]]`

Comment: Also, even though automatic reordering happens, it may be nicer to put the definitions of general `Set` and `SetDelayed` at the end

Comment: Perhaps `Options` and the others can be defined with `:=` as well as `=`. Why do you choose to make `Condition` and `PatternTest` fail?

Answer (score 8):

Here is the functionality I wrote as a part of the static code analyzer, which itself is a part of my effort to construct a FE-based IDE. It takes into account variable localization, and gives only globally-defined symbols, defined in a given piece of code.

Some helper functions:

```
ClearAll[shead];
SetAttributes[shead, HoldAllComplete];
shead[f_Symbol[___]] := HoldComplete[f];
shead[f_[___]] := shead[f];
shead[f_ /; AtomQ[Unevaluated[f]]] := Head[f];

(* TODO: This is a bit too simplisitc, since some pattern symbols \    
might be localized by inner rules inside expr, and should not be \
counted. We might miss some extra dependencies this way *)

ClearAll[getPatternSymbols];
SetAttributes[getPatternSymbols, HoldAllComplete];
getPatternSymbols[expr_] :=
  Cases[
    Unevaluated[expr],
    Verbatim[Pattern][ss_, _] :> HoldComplete[ss],
    {0, \[Infinity]},
    Heads -> True
  ];

ClearAll[getDeclaredSymbols];
SetAttributes[getDeclaredSymbols, HoldAllComplete];
getDeclaredSymbols[{decs___}]:=
  Thread[
    Replace[
      HoldComplete[{decs}],
      HoldPattern[a_=rhs_] :> a,
      {2}
    ]
  ];

getDeclaredSymbols[_]={};


ClearAll[getDeclarationRHSides];
SetAttributes[getDeclarationRHSides, HoldAllComplete];
getDeclarationRHSides[{decs___}]:=
  Cases[
    Unevaluated[{decs}],
    Verbatim[Set][_ , rhs_]:>HoldComplete[rhs],
    {1}
  ];

getDeclarationRHSides[_]:={};


ClearAll[extractSymbolsForUpValues];
SetAttributes[extractSymbolsForUpValues, HoldAllComplete];
extractSymbolsForUpValues[args___] :=
  DeleteCases[
    Cases[
      HoldComplete[args], 
      s_Symbol :> HoldComplete[s], 
      {-1}, 
      Heads -> True
    ],
    HoldComplete[HoldComplete]
  ];
```

The main implementation:

```
ClearAll[definesExt, filter, $defaultExcludes, defInfo];

$defaultExcludes = {HoldComplete[Condition]};

SetAttributes[filter, HoldAllComplete];
filter[sym_Symbol, excluded_]:= filter[HoldComplete[sym], excluded];
filter[held_HoldComplete, excluded_]:= Complement[{held}, excluded];


SetAttributes[definesExt,HoldAllComplete];

definesExt[Verbatim[Unevaluated][expr_],excluded_]:=
definesExt[expr,excluded];

definesExt[
Set[
      (prop: Alternatives[
               Options,
               Attributes,
               DefaultValues,
               OwnValues,
               DownValues,
               SubValues,
               UpValues,
               NValues,
               FormatValues,
               Messages
       ])[sym_Symbol]
       ,
       rhs_], excluded_]:= 
 Join[
   {defInfo[filter[sym,excluded],prop]},
   definesExt[rhs, excluded]
 ];

definesExt[Unset[sym_Symbol],excluded_]:= 
   List @ defInfo[filter[sym,excluded],Unset];

definesExt[(h:(Clear|ClearAll|Remove))[syms__Symbol], excluded_]:=
   List @ defInfo[
     Complement[
        Thread @ HoldComplete[{syms}],
        excluded
     ],
     h
   ];


definesExt[Set[MessageName[sym_,_],rhs_], excluded_]:=
  Join[
    {defInfo[filter[sym,excluded],MessageName]},
    definesExt[rhs, excluded]
  ];

definesExt[
  (h:(Set | SetDelayed | UpSet | UpSetDelayed))[
     Verbatim[Condition][lhs_, cond_], rhs_
  ],
  excluded_
]:=
  With[{excl = Join[excluded, getPatternSymbols[lhs]]},
    Join[
      definesExt[h[lhs,rhs], excluded],
      definesExt[cond, excl]
    ]
  ];


definesExt[
   (h:(TagSet|TagSetDelayed))[tag_Symbol, Verbatim[Condition][lhs_,cond_], rhs_],
    excluded_
]:=
  With[{excl = Join[excluded, getPatternSymbols[lhs]]},
    Join[
      definesExt[h[tag, lhs, rhs], excluded],
      definesExt[cond, excl],
      {defInfo[filter[tag, excluded],h]}
    ]
  ];

definesExt[(h:(Set|SetDelayed))[lhs_Symbol,rhs_], excluded_]:=
  With[{excl=Join[excluded, getPatternSymbols[lhs]]},
    With[{exclFinal = If[h===Set,excluded,excl]},
      Join[
        {defInfo[filter[lhs,excluded],h]},
        definesExt[rhs,exclFinal]
      ]
    ]
  ];


(* TODO: We need a more general parsing scheme for this type of patterns *)

definesExt[
   (h:(Set|SetDelayed))[Verbatim[Pattern][name_Symbol,body_],rhs_],
   excluded_
]:=
  With[{excl = Join[excluded,{HoldComplete[name]}]},
    definesExt[h[body,rhs], excl]
  ];

definesExt[
  (h:(Set|SetDelayed))[
      (head: Verbatim[Pattern][name_Symbol,body_])[args___],
      rhs_
  ], 
  excluded_
]:=
  With[{excl = Join[excluded,{HoldComplete[name]}]},
    definesExt[h[body[args],rhs], excl]
  ]

definesExt[(h:(Set|SetDelayed))[lhs_,rhs_], excluded_]:=
  With[{
    excl=Join[excluded, getPatternSymbols[lhs]],
    head = shead[lhs]
    },
    With[{exclFinal = If[h===Set,excluded,excl]},
      Join[
         definesExt[lhs,excl],
         definesExt[rhs,exclFinal],
         {defInfo[filter[head,excluded],h]}
      ]
    ] /; MatchQ[head,_HoldComplete]
  ];

definesExt[_SetDelayed | _Set, _]:=
   Throw[$Failed, {definesExt, SetDelayed|Set}];

definesExt[(h:(UpSet | UpSetDelayed))[lhs:f_[args___],rhs_],excluded_]:=
  With[{excl = Join[excluded, getPatternSymbols[lhs]]},
    With[{exclFinal = If[h === UpSet,excluded,excl]},
      Join[
        definesExt[lhs,excl],
        definesExt[rhs,exclFinal], 
        {defInfo[Complement[extractSymbolsForUpValues[args], excluded],h]}
      ]
    ]
  ];

definesExt[(h:(TagSet|TagSetDelayed))[tag_Symbol, lhs_, rhs_], excluded_]:=
  With[{excl = Join[excluded, getPatternSymbols[lhs]]},
    With[{exclFinal = If[h === TagSet,excluded,excl]},
      Join[
        definesExt[lhs, excl],
        definesExt[rhs,exclFinal],
        {defInfo[filter[tag, excluded],h]}
      ]
    ]
  ];

definesExt[SetOptions[sym_Symbol,rhs_],excluded_]:= 
  Join[
    {defInfo[filter[sym, excluded],SetOptions]},
    definesExt[rhs, excluded]
  ]

definesExt[SetAttributes[{syms___Symbol},rhs_], excluded_]:=
  Join[
    List @ defInfo[
      Map[
        Function[s,filter[s, excluded],HoldAllComplete],
        Unevaluated[{syms}]
      ],
      SetAttributes
    ],
    definesExt[rhs, excluded]
  ];

definesExt[SetAttributes[sym_Symbol,rhs_], excluded_]:=
  Join[
    {defInfo[filter[sym, excluded],SetAttributes]},
    definesExt[rhs, excluded]
  ];

definesExt[Verbatim[Pattern][_,body_], excluded_]:=
  definesExt[body, excluded];

definesExt[Verbatim[Condition][expr_,cond_],excluded_]:=
  With[{excl=Join[excluded, getPatternSymbols[expr]]},
    Join[
      definesExt[expr, excl],
      definesExt[cond, excl]
    ]
  ]

definesExt[Verbatim[PatternTest][patt_Pattern, fun_], excluded_]:=
  Join[
    definesExt[patt, excluded],
    definesExt[fun, excluded]
  ];

definesExt[Function[Null,body_,atts_], excluded_]:=
  definesExt[body, excluded];

definesExt[body_&, excluded_]:= 
  definesExt[body, excluded];

definesExt[Function[var_,body_], excluded_]:=
  definesExt[Function[{var},body], excluded];

definesExt[Function[{vars__},body_], excluded_]:=
  With[{excl = Join[excluded, Thread[HoldComplete[{vars}]]]},
    definesExt[body, excl]
  ];

(* TODO: the Block case is not clear-cut, whether to include it *)
definesExt[(With | Module | Block)[decs_,body_], excluded_]:=
  With[{rhsides = getDeclarationRHSides[decs]},
    With[{joined = Join[excluded, getDeclaredSymbols[decs]]},
      Join[
        definesExt[body, joined],
        definesExt[rhsides, excluded]
      ]
    ]
  ];

definesExt[f_[elems___], excluded_]:=
  Join[
    definesExt[Unevaluated[f], excluded],
    Sequence @@ Map[
      Function[arg, definesExt[arg, excluded], HoldAllComplete],
      Unevaluated[{elems}]
    ]
  ];

definesExt[a_ /; AtomQ[Unevaluated[a]], _]:={};

definesExt[code_]:=
   With[{excl = $defaultExcludes}, 
     definesExt[code, excl]
   ];

definesExt[args___]:=Throw[$Failed, {definesExt, Hold[args]}];
```

The main idea is that the function maintains a list of currently local symbols, as its second argument. This list gets augmented by symbols localized in a given scoping construct, when the analysis "goes through" this construct. In this way, we exclude localized symbols from the analysis, precisely for the scope where they are localized.

The public function:

```
ClearAll[definesFull];
SetAttributes[definesFull, HoldAllComplete];
definesFull[expr_]:=
  Composition[
    Map[{First@First@#,Tally@#[[All,2]]}&],
    GatherBy[#,First]&,
    Flatten[#,1]&,
    Composition[Thread, List] @@@ #&
  ] @ DeleteCases[definesExt[expr],defInfo[{},_]];
```

The `definesExt` function gives a more detailed information, while `definesFull` computes frequencies of various assignment operators for all assignments for a given symbol, in this piece of code.

I have tested this functionality rather extensively, since it was used for static analysis of large projects (thousands of lines of code, multiple files). Still, it is most certainly incomplete / contains some bugs.

The main possible advantage of this code is that it takes into account variable localization in scoping constructs. Still, the possible disadvantages here is that it does not report assignments to localized variables and functions (intentionally).